# What is the right way to handle (log) custom exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

A situation where a method tries to log a custom exception (custom exception class as code sample) causes a problem:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException() { }
    public CustomException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public CustomException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected CustomException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Creating the exception:

```
CustomException ex = new CustomException("Here is a new custom exception! ");
LogError(ex);
```

Method logging the exceptions (custom and others!):

```
public static void LogError(Exception ex)
{
    //Saving exception messages, inner exceptions etc
    //...
}
```

In this case the ex.Stacktrace of the custom exception is null when logging it!

I believe the reason is that the logging method (which tries to be a general purpose method) takes a Exception object as parameter rather than CustomException (?). What is the correct way to create a logging method, as overloading it with different exception types does seem a bit counterintuitive?

Comment: but `Exception` has a `StackTrace` property, its not exteneded by `CustomException` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell: What are you talking about? StackTrace works fine for all exceptions

Comment: @jgauffin: thats what I mean, All exceptions have a `StackTrace` inherited from the `Exception` so, the statement "I believe the reason is that the logging method (which tries to be a general purpose method) takes a Exception object as parameter rather than CustomException (?)." Must be wrong.

Comment: @Jodrell: ahh, ok. I got confused by  `its not extended`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the reason is that the logging method (which tries to be a general purpose method) takes a Exception object as parameter rather than CustomException (?)

Incorrect. It's null since you have not actually thrown the exception, just created it.

The stacktrace is generated as the exception travels up the callstack. Throwing the exception in the same method as you catch it will only create one stack trace item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
public static void LogError<T>(T exception)
{
  // Serialize the exception here and write to log
}
```

Note that you can simply use any object here in compbination with a human readable serialization format (i.e. formatted Json). Then you can simply log the serialized representation of the object, where all public fields/properties will be preserved.

Note that you'll also need throw/catch for stacktrace to be constructed for you.

Comment: Please explain why a generic method would be better than one using `Exception` as argument. I don't get it.

Comment: I didn't want to constrain the logger just to `Exception` objects. You could argue that I could use 'object' as the argument, but I like to remain strongly typed while using serialization/deserialization.

Comment: I don't see any benefits of having strongly typed objects during serialization since most serializers work with `object` too.

Answer (score 1):

Throw the `CustomException` instance before logging it. The runtime will fill in the stacktrace info

Answer (score 1):

1. Log exceptions in catch block
2. Check logging level and log only message or full exception information.

For example, we use extension methods for [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) to log exceptions:

```
public static void TraceException(this TraceSource traceSource, Exception ex)
{
    traceSource.TraceException(string.Empty, ex);
}

public static void TraceException(this TraceSource traceSource, string comment, Exception ex)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment))
        comment += "\r\n";

    traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, (int)TraceEventType.Error,
            comment + "ExceptionType: {0} \r\n ExceptionMessage: {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);

    if (traceSource.Switch.Level == SourceLevels.Verbose ||
        traceSource.Switch.Level == SourceLevels.All)
    {
        traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _log.TraceException(ex);
}
```